# Rails 3: Validate association and show perfectly the validation to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Fist, I'm using rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.8.7.
I need some help because I couldn't validate and show it perfectly to my user on screen.

The model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :genre
    validates_presence_of :title, :genre
    attr_accessible :genre_id
end
```

The Form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:genre_id, Genre.all(:order => :name), :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select') %>
</div>
```

When I send the form in blank (with the prompt value selectioned by default) the error message appears perfectly "Genre can't be blank" but in the form I receive the html like:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors">
        <label for="book_genre">Genre</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <select name="book[genre_id]" id="book_genre_id">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="2">Gramatic</option>
        <option value="1">Terror</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need the select field inside the div.field_with_erros too because the red background that I defined in CSS.

After that I tried change the f.collection_select :genre_id to :genre

Now I got the select field inside the div.field_with_erros. Owwww yeahhh a victory, for a few moments, until I realize that the validation always accuse error, the rails don't know that the select field :genre is :genre_id that it looks for.

My question is: How to make the :genre change to :genre_id in validation? Or you all guys have a better way to do it?

Keep going in tests I tried change the label and the collection_select to genre_id and the validation works perfectly but without generate the html with the div.field_with_errors so I tried to put the :genre_id in the validates_presence_of so now it look like: "validates_presence_of :title, :genre, :genre_id".

Great, but...

1. When I submit the form and had select the default prompt value the
   validation works fine but they accuse 2 errors, one to :genre and
   another to :genre_id (¬¬) but the html is fine, the label and the
   select is inside the div.field_with_erros.
2. If I submit the form and had select some value from the genres the
       validation and the html is ok.
3. If I submit the form but I had change the value of some option to one invalid to
   test if the validation between models works the validation really
   works fine but the html doesn't created the div.field_with_erros.

Anyone could help me, please?
(Yes, my english isn't the best. Sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

I've created some scaffolded models to test this. I setup 2 migrations:

```
class CreateGenres < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :genres do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :genre
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

in the form I have:

```
<%= f.label :genre_id %>
<%= f.collection_select(:genre_id, Genre.all(:order => :title), :id, :title, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

And in the models I have:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :genre
  validates_presence_of :name, :genre_id
  attr_accessible :name, :genre_id
end
```

The validation then works as I would expect ...

Comment: Hello Chris,
I tried your solution and I get a worst result. I think this isn't what I'm looking for because if I don't validate the :genere a user can choose a genere that already have been excluded or they can change the value to another one by inspect element (firebug). If it isn't what I'm thinking, please, could you explain better to me?

Comment: Sorry, I had write genre in a wrong way, now I fixed in the post, it's because I'm from Brazil so I've translate to English, or nearly. hahahaha (The problem keeps happen)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any way that solves this problem and decided to just check for error in view:

```
<% if f.object.errors.include?(:genre) %>
  <div class='field_with_errors'> 
<% end %>
// :genre field
<% if f.object.errors.include?(:genre) %>
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

Some links:

1. http://railsguides.net/belongs-to-and-presence-validation-rule1/ why to not validate presence of `id` but association itself.
2. https://github.com/frank-west-iii/association_validations difference in validating on `id` or association.
3. http://iada.nl/blog/article/rails-tip-display-association-validation-errors-fields hijack Rails method